# How to compute SSR with just residuals and Xi?

Tags: statistics, sums-of-squares

[image]

How do we calculate SSR? I know SSE is the square of residuals all added together, but SSR is a subtraction between prediction for each observation and the population mean. Not sure how calculate SSR. For SSE, I got 59.960.

Answer (score 1):

You can't compute SSR from the information provided (as you noted), but you don't particularly need it to do those tasks. Note that the Breusch-Pagan test really just requires you to do OLS regression with the *residuals* of the original model, so the information you need is indeed all on the table. Set up a new regression model with the $e_i$ terms as a response variable to the predictor $X_i$ for your next step.

Comment: I got y = -0.56666x when I tried to compute the OLS, but I'm still not sure how I can then get the SSR. I thought we needed SLR to do the Breusch-Pagan test? The mean of the residuals is 0. Not sure how to set up the predicted value - mean. Xi has only -1, 0, 1 as it's values with multiples different residual responses. Does this do anything to the question?

Comment: Yes, we need SLR (simple linear regression) -- my reference to OLS regression (ordinary least squares regression) was just another name for the same thing. You're right that the mean is $0$, which should make the predicted value minus the mean pretty easy. The particular values of the $X_i$ terms are not terribly important here.